# Ignoring a folder from my repo using gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore

Im trying to ignore a wordpress plugin folder form my git repo via `.gitignore`. Ive tried blocking the folder by using :

`/wp-snapshots/*
/wp-snapshots/
wp-snapshots
wp-snapshots/
wp-snapshots/*
/wp-snapshots`

But not of the above works any ideas how i can block this file ?

Comment: Have you staged or committed files in this directory? If so, you must delete it from index. Files may be ignored only if they are untracked.

Answer (score 1):

if your folder name is `wp-snapshots` and you want to block it, your .gitignore file should contain the entry `wp-snapshots` only without slashes. Just make sure that your .gitignore file is located in the  directory which contains the `wp-snapshots` folder.

Thus if your folder structure is `root/plugins/wp-snapshots`, then your .gitignore should be at `root/` or can be at max in `root/plugins/`, but if it is located at say, `root/src`, it won't work.

Comment: Thanks it happened that the `gitignore` file was in the root, but its still not working, i think it may be to do with Wikiii122's comment ill try his changes and let you know

Comment: Got it, it was to do with the fact that the files were marked as staged in my GUI git client (tower), when i unstaged them they were ignored.